# django admin redirecting to custom view

Tags: python, django, admin

In my admin.py I have done..

```
class MediaManagerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MediaManagerAdmin, self).get_urls()
    print "some"
    my_urls = [
        url(r'^mediacontrol/',self.my_view),
    ]
    return my_urls + urls
    print "helloww"

def my_view(self,request):
    return render_to_response("anything.html")
admin.site.register(MediaManager, MediaManagerAdmin)
```

Here what I want is in admin when I click the MediaManager table it should redirect to my custom url `url(r'^mediacontrol/',self.my_view),` with my custom view and template.

But its not redirecting to this url. It is redirecting to the usual admin url. Nothing is changing same like regular admin.

How can I redirect a table to my custom view and template in admin.

Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the regex for your view to the empty string:

```
my_urls = [
    url(r'^$', self.my_view),
]
```

Comment: what if I want to redirect to url with name ?

Comment: What do you mean?  The name of this url will be preserved from the original admin's `urls` but you view will have precedence.

Comment: thank you.. is there any way that I can remove add and change functionality from admin that come along admin template for this MediaManager table?

Comment: You can override the `add_view` and the `change_view` of the `ModelAdmin`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods

Comment: I dont want to change the view just I dont want add and change option or icon in the side of every model. Like I dont want in MediaManager. When I click the model then I want to change and add.

Comment: You can use the CSS to set the `display: none` property for these links.  The CSS selector will be something like this: `div.app-<app_label> tr.model-<model_name> a.add`.